# Backup Samsung Fascinate running ICS, make ODIN-flashable image

Tags: backup, data-recovery, odin, samsung-fascinate, heimdall

I have Samsung Fascinate running ICS. It's very easy to break the OS, such as: by improperly booting into recovery. I want to make a backup, which I could flash using ODIN.

Does anyone know what exactly partitions do I need to backup and what files do I need to put into ODIN tar, in order to get a correctly booting phone immediately after ODIN-flashing?

Here's my mounts:

```
root@android:/ # mount
rootfs / rootfs ro,noatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,nosuid,noatime,mode=0755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,noatime,mode=600 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,noatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,noatime 0 0
none /acct cgroup rw,noatime,cpuacct 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/asec tmpfs rw,noatime,mode=0755,gid=1000 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/obb tmpfs rw,noatime,mode=0755,gid=1000 0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,noatime,cpu 0 0
/dev/block/mtdblock2 /system yaffs2 ro,noatime 0 0
/dev/block/mtdblock3 /cache yaffs2 rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p1 /data ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodiratime,barrier=1,data=writeback,noauto_da_alloc 0 0
/dev/block/mtdblock4 /datadata yaffs2 rw,noatime 0 0
/sys/kernel/debug /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,noatime 0 0
/dev/block/vold/179:9 /mnt/sdcard vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/block/vold/179:9 /mnt/secure/asec vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/sdcard/.android_secure tmpfs ro,noatime,size=0,mode=000,uid=0,gid=0 0 0
```

and all block devices:

```
root@android:/ # ls -l /dev/block
brw------- root     root       7,   0 2012-05-11 11:33 loop0
brw------- root     root       7,   1 2012-05-11 11:33 loop1
brw------- root     root       7,   2 2012-05-11 11:33 loop2
brw------- root     root       7,   3 2012-05-11 11:33 loop3
brw------- root     root       7,   4 2012-05-11 11:33 loop4
brw------- root     root       7,   5 2012-05-11 11:33 loop5
brw------- root     root       7,   6 2012-05-11 11:33 loop6
brw------- root     root       7,   7 2012-05-11 11:33 loop7
brw------- root     root     179,   0 2012-05-11 11:33 mmcblk0
brw------- root     root     179,   1 2012-05-11 11:33 mmcblk0p1
brw------- root     root     179,   2 2012-05-11 11:33 mmcblk0p2
brw------- root     root     179,   3 2012-05-11 11:33 mmcblk0p3
brw------- root     root     179,   8 2012-05-11 11:33 mmcblk1
brw------- root     root     179,   9 2012-05-11 11:33 mmcblk1p1
brw------- root     root      31,   0 2012-05-11 11:33 mtdblock0
brw------- root     root      31,   1 2012-05-11 11:33 mtdblock1
brw------- root     root      31,   2 2012-05-11 11:33 mtdblock2
brw------- root     root      31,   3 2012-05-11 11:33 mtdblock3
brw------- root     root      31,   4 2012-05-11 11:33 mtdblock4
brw------- root     root      31,   5 2012-05-11 11:33 mtdblock5
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2012-05-11 11:33 platform
brw------- root     root       1,   0 2012-05-11 11:33 ram0
brw------- root     root       1,   1 2012-05-11 11:33 ram1
brw------- root     root       1,  10 2012-05-11 11:33 ram10
brw------- root     root       1,  11 2012-05-11 11:33 ram11
brw------- root     root       1,  12 2012-05-11 11:33 ram12
brw------- root     root       1,  13 2012-05-11 11:33 ram13
brw------- root     root       1,  14 2012-05-11 11:33 ram14
brw------- root     root       1,  15 2012-05-11 11:33 ram15
brw------- root     root       1,   2 2012-05-11 11:33 ram2
brw------- root     root       1,   3 2012-05-11 11:33 ram3
brw------- root     root       1,   4 2012-05-11 11:33 ram4
brw------- root     root       1,   5 2012-05-11 11:33 ram5
brw------- root     root       1,   6 2012-05-11 11:33 ram6
brw------- root     root       1,   7 2012-05-11 11:33 ram7
brw------- root     root       1,   8 2012-05-11 11:33 ram8
brw------- root     root       1,   9 2012-05-11 11:33 ram9
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2012-05-11 11:33 vold
```

**EDIT:** I am aware of following methodology, I could use to restore phone:

- ODIN froyo or gingerbread image,
- ODIN clockworkmod with ICS fix,
- Install firmware from zip file
- Restore nandroid backup

My question is specifically, how do I avoid having to go through all of this, and just make ODIN-flashable restore.

Comment: You need to back up *everything* that isn't on the data partition if I'm not mistaken.  You can skip the bootloader though since it's generally a very bad idea to touch that.  In fact I'd say this is a bad idea in general -- you want to be darn sure you're flashing good stuff with Odin, which means not something you might have screwed up before backing it up :P.

Comment: If you create a normal Nandroid backup, the steps to a full restore are Odin to stock / install CWM / restore backup, which doesn't take much longer.  I would tell you how to do this anyways except that I don't know which partitions are mapped to which Odin images :P

Comment: @MatthewRead Thanks for the answer, but my question is specifically about making ODIN flashable restore image. Although you think differently, it does take a long time to do all the steps you brought up here, and it is a lot of manual work, and many chances to forget something. I want to make a package I could restore without having to remember details

Answer (score -1):

I have the same idea once,but its hard to achieve.
if use gingerbread ,you can reference the official rom,and make replacement,
but for ics, there different partitions,you  maybe hard to suceess.

Comment: What is it you're trying to say?

Comment: @AlEverett I think what he is trying to say is that with ICS it is challenging to make ODIN-flashable image because of different than GB partition structure.

Comment: @HenryWu I am not sure why would anyone give you a -1 for the answer, and it really bothers me that someone -1'ed this thread. I see no reason why asking questions, or posting answers about android recovery is considered inappropriate on this site. Even though you didn't answer my question I will +1 you anyway

Comment: @galets: There is nothing inherently wrong with questions about recovery or Odin on this site. This specific answer, though, could likely have been downvoted because it is very poorly-written and difficult to understand, or because (by your own admission) it does not answer your question. I encourage you to consider not upvoting posts unless you find them genuinely useful, though ultimately you are free to vote however you wish.

Comment: @eldarerathis it might be poorly written, but it's possible to understand what he is trying to say, and he clearly has a valid point. What makes me wonder is why in the world is someone so insistent on keeping his answer at -1. What about my question? Is it also poorly written? I have a feeling this site is being manipulated, no wonder you can't get any good answers here.

Comment: @galets: Downvoting poor content hardly qualifies as "manipulation", it's the entire purpose of the voting system. I have no idea why your question was downvoted - only the person who cast the vote could tell you - but they are under no obligation to do so. It's annoying sometimes, sure, but anonymity is core to the voting system and extremely unlikely to change anytime soon.

Comment: @eldarerathis that might be true, but follow me. My question sits with "-1" on it, so it's pretty much buried. Rating pretty much blocks most wanderers from checking it out. The HenryWu guy is obviously a new account. Nobody is paying extra attention to his comments. So, the moment he posted, somebody opened a buried, several-days-old thread to downvote him. Coincidence? maybe. So, time passes, nothing happens. I upvote him, and almost immediately after that someone gets him back to "-1". Under which scenario would you say such thing would normally happen?

Comment: @galets: The [`/review` page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84693/eeeek-i-sense-an-eeeek-question-about-missing-a-unanswered-tab/88954#88954) has a tab that displays "First Answers" posted by accounts. This is this user's first answer, and it was how I landed on this answer. I would not be surprised if other people did as well since `/review` is visible to anyone with >=200 rep. Answering a question also bumps it to the top of the active list.